# A "safe place" to eval trusted code in Javascript (with specific context)? [Edit: how can you break it?]

Tags: javascript, scope, eval

Don't judge me yet on the title, I know eval is evil, but there are reasons I do it that way, and it will be very limited. Here is the thing: I want to create a safe space where i can run specific (and trusted) bits of code, and retrieve the result (if it fits to what i expect). For security reasons, I wanted to cut it from all other scopes (this space is asked for the result, and is supposed not to be able to export anything to surrounding scopes by itself).

I came to a solution which seems to work, that also can add a context to the execution, but i'm not sure if it is valid, or if there are security breaches in this system. Can you please tell me if there is something wrong with it?

It actually creates local vars with same name as the global ones, to prevent accessing to them. It also strips functions (I will add feature to preserve the ones I want to keep). The function is declared closest from globals as possible, to avoid visibility of local scopes that would be higher (a parameter to remove these specific local vars is planned).

```
function contextNoScope(root, context) {
    //I had to pass window as parameter for it to work properly
    for(var key in root){
        if(key != '0' && key != 'window'){
            eval('var ' + key + '=undefined;');
        }
    }
    var window = undefined;
    var root = undefined; //root has to be forbidden too
    return function() {
        this.eval = function(str){ return eval(str); };
        return this;
    }.call(context);
}
```

**USAGE:**

```
(function(root){
    function contextNoScope(root, context) {
        //...same as previous
    }
    var context = { x: 3 };
    var space = contextNoScope(root, context);
    console.log(space.eval('this.x + 1'));
})(window);
```

(NOTE: if you test this code in a global way, don't forget to add a special fix if you pass a global var for the context, because it will be masked like all the others. A fix has to be added also if you want try to pass window as the context parameter, for obvious reasons..)

**EDIT:**

To make things clearer about what the scripts do and what can solve my problem: I assume there is no total safety in JS with what can be called 'trusted source', as we are obviously talking here about importing scripts. By trusted I mean that the script origin will be checked, and security keys added, to begin with.

Each script takes a certain variable from the given context and adds a property to it. The names here are given, meaning that we know beforehand which var will be modified and what is the name and type of the property added to it. In a way I can already check if what is done was intended or not, the problem here is to be "sure" that any code won't be able to interfere with events or the DOM mostly, and doesn't remove or modify anything in the given context except adding the propery..

**EDIT 2: please break it!**

(I'm not yet specialist of all the site rules, correct me if it's not the way to properly edit: i chose not to modify the first code and add the new version, even if it gets a bit long.)

I am heading for a proper sandbox for my solution, made by better people than me, but because I am curious and want to keep learning, I post here an improved version of what i did, because I'd like to know how this still can be broken. *So i am now looking for precise tricks that can break this system:*

```
function contextNoScope(context) {
    var len, i, keys, val, window = root, isNaN = root.isNaN, console = root.console;
    if(!context){ context = {}; }
    keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window);
    if(len = keys.length){
        for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
            val = keys[i];
            //TODO: remove 'console' from the if (debug purpose)
            if(isNaN(val) && val != 'window' && val != 'eval' && val != 'isNaN' && val != 'console'){
                eval('var ' + val + '=undefined;');
            }
        }
    }
    isNaN = undefined;
    len = undefined;
    i = undefined;
    keys = undefined;
    val = undefined;
    eval('var root = undefined');
    return function() {
        this.eval = function(str){
            if(str){
                str = str.toString();
                //TODO: replace by more relevant regex (it currently throws error for words like 'evaluation')
                if(str.indexOf('constructor') > -1 || str.indexOf('__proto__') > -1 || str.indexOf('prototype') > -1 || str.indexOf('eval') > -1){
                    console.log('ERROR - str contains forbidden code "constructor", "__proto__", "eval", "prototype"', '\n' + str);
                    return false;
                }
                try{
                    eval(str);
                    return true;
                }catch(e){
                    console.log(e + '\nin:\n' + str);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            console.log('ERROR - str is not defined: ', str);
            return false;
        };
        return this;
    }.call(context);
}
```

Some explanations for the changes:

- In the first version i added window as a parameter because of a basic mistake about when the word `var` is evaluated, it is not necessary. But passing window as another name ('root' here) seems easier. The whole function is wrapped the same way as in the first version usage.
- added `getOwnPropertyNames` to get also the non-enumerable properties, but I know about the backwards compatibility issue, that is not what I mean by 'break the system' to use an older browser (I know it already)
- added masking of the function local parameters or variables
- the test for `isNaN(val)` is here to not evaluate as a variable the numbers-properties of window, that reference the i-frames
- `eval('var root = undefined');` is a trick for the var to be created at the moment the line is executed, not at the very beginning, like it would be with a regular `var`
- I am aware that functions declared in this space don't access regular functions anymore (try with an `alert(1)`, it won't work)

Comment: Yes, You are doing right because most frameworks use the same approach(i.e anonymous function) as you are using to separate different scopes.

Comment: Don't do this. Creating a "safe place" is error-prone and overcomplicated and whatever you do will likely have a loophole. If you are *trusting* the evaled code, you should be able to trust it only to use local variables. If you want to prevent accidental bugs, run the codes through a linter that disallows undeclared variables.

Comment: What about non-enumerable properties of `root`? Why treat `0` and `window` special? What's this `return function() {…}.call(context)` thing, why not simply `context.eval = function(str) { return eval(str) }; return context;`?

Comment: thx for your answers. Yes, non-enumerable properties were not totally overlooked, i was already thinking about a way to do it, which proves harder than expected: (('hello'.constructor.constructor)('console.log("hello from global")'))(); seems to break the space no matter if String is redefined or not, and I dont really want to go to the point to hide all constructors and such. Maybe i'll try with a bigger sandbox tool made by someone.. the only alternative is to use a global var for my imports and delete it when done, but i wanted to avoid it because values can be listened to via the console.

Comment: To answer your other questions:
_0 cannot be defined as a var name, and i cannot set window to undefined before the loop is ended, they are treated separately
_my problem is actually that the code must create a variable (that i retreive in the process), i just would like it not to modify anything that already exists.
_the return function trick is for the eval to be executed on the specific context given as parameter, which would not be the case with a direct call (which would execute it in the context of the "contextNoScope" function)

Comment: Your attempt at using a "*more relevant regex*" is **doomed to fail**. You cannot do that generically. Regarding the function, no your code does not do that. If you want to be safe against `context.eval` being called on something else, you should use `context.eval = function(str) { return eval(str) }.bind(context); return context;`.

Comment: Interesting, but it has more became a question of curiosity about deep aspects of JS than if this pattern is reasonable or not.. I don't want to waste your time but could you be more specific? If there is no way to consistently detect an eval, how can JS engines be able to do it? Or do you mean it would not be time proof? I don't see either how would your version (that i will try) would prevent an `eval` inside the string to be executed?

Answer (score 0):

Anything that's based on setting variables to shadow globals can be broken by `Function.apply(undefined)`, which runs a function with `this` set to the global context. For instance:

```
(function() {
    this.alert(1);
}).apply(undefined);
```

Anything that's based on regular expressions can probably be broken by some combination of:

- Escaping
- `new Function`, `eval`, etc
- Constructing strings using [non-alphanumeric Javascript expressions](http://patriciopalladino.com/blog/2012/08/09/non-alphanumeric-javascript.html)

Bottom line: You cannot build an effective sandbox out of Javascript. It's been tried; every attempt has been complicated, fragile, and eventually broken.